# Object of type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot be converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Guid]'

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

Similar problem to what's asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100222/object-of-type-system-windows-data-binding-cannot-be-converted-to-type-system), but it looks like the cause of this exception in this case is different. Perhaps I've set up my property wrong?

I've got a custom usercontrol, which I want to bind to. However, InitializeComponent throws the error `Object of type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot be converted to type 'System.Nullable 1[System.Guid]'` VS says it's the set property that's throwing this error.

I simplified my property to try and find the error, but it still happens without any setter logic

```
public Guid? SelectedItemGUID
{
    get
    {
        if (SelectedItem == null) return null;
        else return (Guid)SelectedItem.GetType().GetProperty("GUID").GetValue(SelectedItem, null);
    }
    set
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

I'm binding to in the XAML using (client.BIllToClient is a `Guid?`)

```
SelectedItemGUID="{Binding Path=client.BillToClient, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing your property with this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemGUIDProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedItemGUID",
        typeof(Guid?),
        typeof(UserControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null)
    );

public Guid? SelectedItemGUID
{
    public Guid? SelectedItemGUID
    {
        get { return (Guid?)GetValue(SelectedItemGUIDProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemGUIDProperty, (Guid?)SelectedItem.GetType().GetProperty("GUID").GetValue(SelectedItem, null)); }
    }
}
```

I think you are trying to bind a simple C# property. WPF binding requires the binding target to be a `DependencyProperty`. See docs on [custom bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I have `typeof(UserControl)` as the parent type in the above code; you will need to replace it with the type of your control.

Comment: Right you are! I managed to figure this out finally liiiike 5 minutes before you posted. I'd never used DependencyProperties before, but now I know all about them.